# ¿Cómo determinar que un número es la suma de otros dos?

Tags: c

Quiero hacer un codigo que me pida 3 numeros, y luego podamos determinar si el tercer numero es la suma de los primeros 2, yo pensaba que podria ser esta formula

```
numero1+numero2=suma
if (suma=numero3)
imprimir (si es la suma)
```

pero no funciona.

Soy nuevo en esto de la programacion y estoy aprendiendo a utilizar stdio pero en este momento no se que va mal con mi codigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En C la comparación se hace con `==` y no con `=`, que es asignación

Comment: Siempre puedes consultar alguna [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions) para saber los operadores disponibles.

Comment: si estás aprendiendo a programar yo no empezaría con el lenguaje de programación c, yo empezaría con java, c# y luego saltaría a javascript y python y en tercera instancia a c/c++. Solo un consejo

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis sería

```
var suma = numero1 + numero2
```

Ya que el = sirve como "asignación". Entonces, la línea anterior se leería: *"La sumatoria de numero1 y numero2 se lo voy a asignar a la variable suma"*

y luego

```
if (suma == numero3)
{
  imprimir
}
```

Usualmente en la *mayoría* de lenguajes, para comparar variables se usa doble igual y para asignar sólo un igual. Pero si aun estás escribiendo pseudocódigo, podría estar bien usar un igual ya que estás entendiendo correctamente lo que se debe de hacer.